# Cloud foundry ignoring the resolved module path from package-lock.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, cloud-foundry, buildpack

We are using a Node.js buildpack to deploy our app to cloud foundry. We are using artifactory to resolve the modules. To cloud foundry we push package.json together with package-lock.json where all the dependencies have their paths pointing to artifactory.

Unfortunately cloud foundry is ignoring the resolved path from the package-lock file and is trying to get the packages from the public registry. Thanks for any help!

Expected behavior:

- packages are downloaded from the paths provided in package-lock.json

Current behavior:

- packages are downloaded from public registry

```
-----> Building dependencies

          Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock.json)

   npm ERR! code E404

   npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<package_name> - Not found

   npm ERR! 404 

   npm ERR! 404  '<package_name>@0.1.6' is not in the npm registry.

   npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

   npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'app'

   npm ERR! 404 

   npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

   npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase

FAILED

script returned exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that npm does not use the `resolved` urls that you see in the `package-lock.json` file to download missing packages.

In order to get the Cloud Foundry node.js buildpack to connect to your own npm registry, you need to include a `.npmrc` file in the directory that you are pushing to Cloud Foundry (see [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/issues/79#issuecomment-281573114)). You can do this easily with the `npm config` command, for example:

```
npm config --location project set registry http://some-registry.com
```

It seems like the [Artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry#npmRegistry-UsingthenpmCommandLine) describes this process, although please note that if you leave off `--location project` your changes will go into your global .npmrc file which will not be uploaded to Cloud Foundry.

You can read more about .npmrc in the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc) and a description of the `registry` setting can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#registry).